# Need to compare how a table changes from prior day to current day and the table doesn't have a field to track record creation or modification in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS, I need help determining the records that were added or modified from the prior business day.  The table that contains the data doesn't have a field to track creation or modification date.

I assume I need to store the result each day and compare the stored result to the next business day that I run the report.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to store the status somewhere -- and typically it is easiest to have that info with your original data. Are you sure you can't change it so that it would contain the time of last modify?

Answer (score 0):

Without any info on when records are created or modified this is going to be more painful than it needs to be.

As I see it you have a couple of options.

1. Add the required column(s). For creation you can set a default value of `getdate()` and then add a trigger on updates to modify the updated date column. This way it will be easy to query the table for anything that has changed in the last day or over any period of time you require.
2. Get the dataset query that runs in your report to make a copy of the table each time it runs into a separate table e.g. `myTable_Previous`. You can then query the differences between the two. There are several problems with this approach that means it's not a good idea.

a. it will only work between report executions so if the report runs 3 times in a day it will only be comparing since the last run which may have been 5 minutes ago.

b. if the report is not run for a week it will show you changes for that time period

c. you would need to have the report scheduled via a subscription to ensure it was run at the correct interval.

d. if the table you are querying is big it will mean copying a lot of data each time the report is run which will slow it down

In short, the best way is to add the required info and do it correctly, it will make any similar reports/queries easier to write in the future.